# jquery row selection from index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want, given a table id and a row index (0-based), to select the row at that index so that I can apply a background color to all of its td's.  I'm familiar with basic selection, but am not sure how to do this using an index variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$('#id tbody > tr').eq(rowindex)
```

or, per your request in comments:

```
$('#id tbody > tr').eq(rowindex).children().addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Thanks..would you mind showing me how to add a class to each td under the matching tr?

Comment: $('#id tbody > tr').eq(rowindex).children().addClass('myfunkyClass');

Answer (score 0):

var selectedRow = 4
$('#myID tr:eq(' + selectedRow + ')');

would give you the 5th row.

Comment: I prefer the functional version to avoid concatenating and parsing a selector.  It's supposedly more efficient, too.

Comment: Yes you quiet right because $('#myID') would use native js document.getElementById ratehr than working through sizzle. Well spotted.

Comment: I'm not so much worried about sizzle's performance, as with building selectors based on other variables.

Answer (score 0):

$(#tableID)[0].rows[rowNumber]

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see any reasons from your example why you would addClass to each cell of a row. Unless, off course, you want to select a custom set of row cells. If not, you can simply apply a class, for ex "selected", to your selected row and write css like this:

```
tr td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
tr.selected td {
    background-color: #fffccc;
}
```

Or you can even try to set a background-color of a whole row.

Good luck!

Comment: there are times when you specifically want the `<td>` elements to get the class, not the outer `<tr>`, for example if adding cell borders.

Comment: Absolutely true :) But in this particular case @bill wanted to change a background color of a selected row. In other cases, like border color, off course, the `.addClass('selected')` should be executed on each `<td>` of the selected `<tr>`.